# Proper dependency injection in Android with(out) DI containers (Dagger 1)

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dagger

I am currently developing (actually structuring) an Android app with Bluetooth connection & HTTP communication with RESTful service. I happened to come across a "dependency injection" framework called Dagger, and it was quite revolutionary to me. However, I started to contemplate more upon the "true spirit" of dependency injection and came across even more blog posts/opinions explaining the concept and actually suggesting the use of "constructor injection" and labelling others (field and setter injections) as "anti-patterns."

I do get their concerns with field and setter injections via DI frameworks, as former does not explicitly reveal an object's dependency, and the latter does not make a dependency strictly "required." However some voice strong opinions that the only valid-and-useful-and-truly-object-oriented-way of dependency injection is constructor injection.

My concern is in particular with Android. Developing an Android app means dealing with a lot of activities, services, fragments, broadcast receivers and so forth, and many of them do not let us handle the constructor. To provide dependencies using DI containers (Dagger), I just had to use field injection for dependencies. **Why not use POJO Factories?** The only advantage of using DI framework for field injection seems to be the ability to provide separate modules (one for production and one that injects mock objects for testing), but I don't know if it's worth introducing the performance overhead (if there's any).

For now, the only advantage, in my strictly limited point of view, of using Dagger is reducing the amount of code to write and avoiding the headaches that come with wiring the objects to pass on dependencies properly.

Thus, I came to a conclusion that I maybe totally misunderstanding the concept of dependency injection or/and I am missing out on the **proper way to use Dagger**, or/and maybe I am being too opinionated (or just not really that competent) in object oriented design.

Please educate me with the proper use of DI container and lack of insight/understanding!

Comment: I have the EXACT same issue. I wish someone would help out. Every tutorial I've seen just advocates using the constructor to inject the dependencies but this won't work in Android as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Not having to deal with wiring classes together is a huge advantage, not having to re-wire during a refactor is an even bigger advantage.

I find your "only advantage" is still a huge advantage. IMHO, the most valuable part of DI comes when you are adding to or refactoring existing code. Very frequently, I come across a situation where something at a "leaf" of the dependency graph needs some extra thing from the root of the graph (ie UserStorageHelper needs a Context). Without DI, it would be necessary to pass that object through every layer of constructor and/or onCreate/onAttach between some root and the target dependency. DI will allow you to add that dependency with minimal refactor cost. IMO, it makes the code more understandable, as at each level, you can inspect and say "this object needs some set of dependencies". Whatever sub-dependencies those objects have is not immediately useful information, but you can check that easily as well. (Dagger also generates the dependency graph if you want an overview, which I think is pretty neat.)

The counter to that, is changing the dependencies of a "leaf" object can cause a ripple effect up the graph that isn't necessarily immediately obvious. However, I typically find fixing a DI issue better than a potentially massive refactor when you need to modify every constructor in the dependency graph.

For the suggestion about using POJO factories instead, it seems to me that you still have the same dependency issue. Each layer of the factory will need another factory to get its dependencies. Writing that yourself seems just as tedious, so you could code generate it, but now you basically just have dagger's Provider.

Beyond supplying different implementations in testing, I have also used it extensively used it to handle build flavours/dimensions/build types (injecting different types of logger modules? no-op vs real ad modules?).

Ultimately, usefulness depends entirely on your project. Dagger/DI is very useful in many situations, but not every situation. Kind of like a multi-tool, you can use it in a lot of different ways. Sometimes it is overkill (you only needed a screw-driver, not a wine bottle opener) and sometimes it just doesn't solve your problem (it just won't make a good hammer no matter how hard you try). The only caveat to that is that it is much harder to add DI in later than it is to use it from the start, so I tend to err on the side of adding it as the overkill option at the start of a project, rather than getting into a project and wishing I already had it.

Comment: This is honestly a great answer. At the beginning of a recent project I started out with Dagger and it seemed like an overkill. As the project progressed I found myself in the exact situation that you described above (refactoring just to add dependencies at the leaf classes). Later I was happy that I left Dagger in my code :) Since Android specific classes with life cycles tend to not support explicit constructor calls anyways, your idea seems very reasonable and I can totally and pragmatically agree now. Thanks for being so clear on this issue!